# Как лучше реализовать вывод документа в qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Вот есть компания, к ней можно прикрепить, предположим, один документ. Будь это .png или .doc, не суть. Как бы это грамотно реализовать? Есть для этого удобные инструменты?

Пока этим никогда не занимался. Есть мысли в БД хранить путь к файлу, состоящий из уникального id компании и расширения. Хранить эти документы, в будущем, где-то в папке recources, верно? А как выводить эти документы? Делать pixmap для label, если это png, а .doc как привязать? Или же каким-то образом открывать все эти файлы путем программ по умолчанию, то есть нажимаешь на файлик - открывается Windows Фото если это .png или Word если .doc. В общем, кто сталкивался с этим - признавайтесь, как лучше реализовать подобную фичу :) Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно прикрепить один документ, значит можно и два. Храните все документы в отдельной коллекции/дереве в БД или в файловой системе, в объекте организации храните ссылку/массив ссылок на документы в виде IRI или UUID. Ну или в виде численного идентификатора.

Если используете IRI, разрешайте их относительно какого-то корневого каталога/узла БД, не ссылайтесь напрямую на файловую систему через `file:///`. Можно поднять http сервер, иди можно ввести свою схему IRI, и разрешать ссылки вручную, по тем же принципам, которые используются в web. IRI становится особенно полезен, когда документ сам начинает содержать ссылки на другие документы.

Конвертируйте .doc в PDF, и выводите либо через Qt PDF, либо через WebEngineView. Теоретически можно встроить конвертер в PDF прямо в приложение (например, есть библиотеки для Python, а Python можно вызывать из Qt), но обычно хорошие конвертеры зависят от приложения MS Word, из-за чего проще экспортировать в PDF сразу при заливке.

Картинки и svg удобно выводить на QGraphicsScene (т.к. можно относительно просто реализовать масштабирование), или через WebEngineView. Ну или через  QML.

Выбор инструментов во многом зависит от версии Qt. Например, на OpenSuse c Qt 5.12 нет Qt PDF, т.к. это экспериментальный пакет. А в Qt 5.11 pdf нет и в WebEngine, только через сторонние js библиотеки.